# Mocking Test : How-to refactor legacy singleton used in static

Tags: unit-testing, jakarta-ee, mocking, singleton, refactoring

Well, I'm looking for the best way to refactor a (huge) legacy code-base and introducing some tests in it..There was no test framework. (yeah, I mean not at all)

It was an JEE 5 application. The goal is to revamp that in JEE7

Let me introduce a quick overview .
The end-users (those of them who are authorized) are free to evolve , configure many aspect of the application behavior by setting in the UI a bunch of preferences.
Theses are stored in an SQL table for the main part (the rest in some xml and properties files).
To fulfill this requirement, there is an **@Startup** object dedicated to build a sort-of huge map with all key-values.
Then all across the code base when a use case needs to adapt it's processing it checks the current value of the parameter(s) needed to its task.

A real case is that the app has to do a few operations on images;
For instance, Class ImgProcessing has to create thumbnail of a picture via this method :

`Optional<Path> generateThumb_fromPath(Path origImg);`

for this the method generateThumb_fromPath,  calls Thumbnailer,
which uses a generic ImageProcessingHelper,
which holds a few set of generic image related tools and methods,
and specially an static method returning the wished dimensions of the thumbnail   to be generated based on the original image constraints and some thumbnail  preferences (keys = "THUMBNAIL_WIDTH" and "THUMBNAIL_HEIGHT").

These preferences are the user wishes for what size a thumbnail should have.
So far so good, nothing special.

*Now the dark side of this :*
The original JEE5 config loader is an bad old fashioned infamous singleton pattern as :

```
OldBadConfig {
private static OldBadConfig instance ;
   public static getInstance(){
   if(instance==null){
   // create, initialize and populate our big preferences' map
   }
   return instance;
   }
}
```

Then all across the whole code-base these preferences are used. In my refactoring effort I've already done using **@Inject** for injecting the singleton object.
But in static utilities ( *no injection point available* ) you have lots of this nasty calls :
***OldBadConfig.getInstance.getPreference(key, defaultValue)***

(Briefly I will explain that I use testNg + Mockito,  I don't think the tools are relevant here, it seems to be more about an original terrible design,
 but if I HAVE to change my toolbox (Junit or whatever) I will. But again I don't think the tooling is the root problem here. )

Trying to refactor the image part and make it test-friendly., I want to do this test with  *cut = instance of my Class Under Test:*

```
@Test
public void firstTest(){
 Optional<Path> op = cut.generateThumb_fromPath(targetPath);
// ..assertThatTheThumbnailWasCreated........
}
```

So in a few words , 
the execution flow will be like :
*class under test --> some business implementation -->  someutilities -->  **static_global_app_preference** ---> other_class-othermethod.finalizingProcessing,*
then return to the caller.

My testing effort halts here. How to mock the static_global_app_preference ?
How can I refactor the  static_global_app_preference part from

```
*OldBadConfig.getInstance.getPreference(key, defaultValue)*
```

to something mockable where I could mock like :

```
Mockito.when(gloablConf.getPreference("THUMBNAIL_WIDTH", anyString)).thenReturn("32");
```

I've spent quite a time reading boks, blog posts etc all saying
'(these kind of) Singleton is EVIL'. You should NOT do that ! 
I think we all agree , thanks.
**But what about a real word and effective solution to such really trivial, common tasks?**
 I can not add the singleton instance (or the preferences'map ) as parameters (because as it is already spread all across the code-base it will pollute all and every classes and methods . For instance in the exposed use case, it will pollute 5 methods in 4 classes just for one, poor, miserable, access to a parameter.
 It's really not feasible.

So far I tried to refactor OldBadConfig class in two part : one with all initialization/write stuff, 
and the other with only the read parts. that way I can at least make this a real JEE @Singleton and benefits from concurrent access once the startup is over and the configuration all loaded.

Then I tried to make this SharedGlobalConf accessible via a factory, called like :

```
   SharedGlobalConf gloablConf=   (new SharedGlobalConfFactory()).getShared();  
   then gloablConf.getPreference(key, defaultValue);    is accessible.
```

It seems to be a little better than the original bottleneck, but didn't help at all for the testing part.
I thought the factory will ease everything but nothing like that comes out.

So there is my question :
For myself, I can split the OldBadConfig  to an startup artefact doing the init and refesh, and to an SharedGlobalConf which is a JEE7 pure Singleton,

```
@Singleton
@ConcurrencyManagement(ConcurrencyManagementType.BEAN)
@Lock(LockType.READ)
```

Then, as for the legacy use case described here,  How Can I make this *reasonably* mock-able ? Real word solutions are all welcomed.
Thanks sharing your wisdom and skills !

Answer (score 1):

I will like to share my own answer.
Let's say we got these classes after the initial large OldBadConfig class was splitted :
  `@Startup` `AppConfigPopulator`  in charge of loading all information and populating the kind-of internal cache,
which is now a distinct `SharedGlobalConf` object. The populator is the only one in charge of feeding the SharedGlobalConf via :

```
@Override
    public SharedGlobalConf sharedGlobalConf() {
        if (sharedGlobalConf.isDirty()) {
            this.refreshSharedGlobalConf();
        }
        return sharedGlobalConf;

    }

    private void refreshSharedGlobalConf() {
        sharedGlobalConf.setParams(params);
        sharedGlobalConf.setvAppTempPath_temp(getAppTempPath_temp());
    }
```

In all components (by that I mean all Classes holding valid injection points) you just do your classic
  `@Inject     private SharedGlobalConf globalConf;`

For static utilities that can not do @Inject, we got an `SharedGlobalConfFactory` which handles the shared data to everything in a one-liner :

```
SharedGlobalConf gloablConf = (new SharedGlobalConfFactory()).getShared();
```

That way our old code base can be smoothly upgraded : @Inject in all valid components, And the (too many) old utilities that we can not reasonably rewrite them all in this refactoring step can get these

```
*OldBadConfig.getInstance.getPreference(key, defaultValue)*
```

,simply replaced by

```
(new SharedGlobalConfFactory()).getShared().getPreference(key, defaultValue);
```

And we are test-compliant and mockable !

### Proof of concept :

A really critical Business demands is modeled in this class :

```
  @Named
public class Usage {
 static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Usage.class);
@Inject
private SharedGlobalConf globalConf;@Inject
private BusinessCase bc;public String doSomething(String argument) {
    logger.debug(" >>doSomething on {}", argument);
    // do something using bc
    Object importantBusinessDecision = bc.checks(argument);
    logger.debug(" >>importantBusinessDecision :: {}", importantBusinessDecision);

    if (globalConf.isParamFlagActive("StackOverflow_Required", "1")) {
        logger.debug(" >>StackOverflow_Required :: TRUE");
        // Do it !
        return "Done_SO";
    } else {
        logger.debug(" >>StackOverflow_Required :: FALSE -> another");
        // Do it another way
        String resultStatus = importantBusinessDecision +"-"+ StaticHelper.anotherWay(importantBusinessDecision);
        logger.debug(" >> resultStatus " + resultStatus);
        return "Done_another_way " + resultStatus;
    }
}
public void err() {
    xx();
}
private void xx() {
   throw new UnsupportedOperationException(" WTF !!!"); 
}
```

}

To get it's job done , we need a hand from our old companion `StaticHelper` :

`class StaticHelper {
    public static String anotherWay(Object importantBusinessDecision) {// System.out.println("zz @anotherWay on "+importantBusinessDecision);
        SharedGlobalConf gloablConf = (new SharedGlobalConfFactory()).getShared();
        String avar = gloablConf.getParamValue("deeperParam", "deeperValue");
        //compute the importantBusinessDecision based on avar
        return avar;
    }
}`

Usage of this =

```
@Named public class Usage {

 static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Usage.class);

@Inject
private SharedGlobalConf globalConf;

@Inject
private BusinessCase bc;

public String doSomething(String argument) {
    logger.debug(" >>doSomething on {}", argument);
    // do something using bc
    Object importantBusinessDecision = bc.checks(argument);
    logger.debug(" >>importantBusinessDecision :: {}", importantBusinessDecision);

    if (globalConf.isParamFlagActive("StackOverflow_Required", "1")) {
        logger.debug(" >>StackOverflow_Required :: TRUE");
        // Do it !
        return "Done_SO";
    } else {
        logger.debug(" >>StackOverflow_Required :: FALSE -> another");
        // Do it another way
        String resultStatus = importantBusinessDecision +"-"+ StaticHelper.anotherWay(importantBusinessDecision);
        logger.debug(" >> resultStatus " + resultStatus);
        return "Done_another_way " + resultStatus;
    }
}
public void err() {
    xx();
}
private void xx() {
   throw new UnsupportedOperationException(" WTF !!!"); 
}}
```

As you see the old shared key/value holder is still used every where but this time, ***we can test***

```
public class TestingAgainstOldBadStaticSingleton {
private final Boolean boolFlagParam;
private final String deepParam;
private final String decisionParam;
private final String argument;
private final String expected;
@Factory(dataProvider = "tdpOne")
public TestingAgainstOldBadStaticSingleton(String argument, Boolean boolFlagParam, String deepParam, String decisionParam, String expected) {
    this.argument = argument;
    this.boolFlagParam = boolFlagParam;
    this.deepParam = deepParam;
    this.decisionParam = decisionParam;
    this.expected = expected;
}
@Mock
SharedGlobalConf gloablConf = (new SharedGlobalConfFactory()).getShared();
@Mock
BusinessCase bc = (new BusinessCase());
@InjectMocks
Usage cut = new Usage();
@Test
public void testDoSomething() {
    String result = cut.doSomething(argument);
    assertEquals(result, this.expected);
}
@BeforeMethod
public void setUpMethod() throws Exception {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    Mockito.when(gloablConf.isParamFlagActive("StackOverflow_Required", "1")).thenReturn(this.boolFlagParam);
    Mockito.when(gloablConf.getParamValue("deeperParam", "deeperValue")).thenReturn(this.deepParam);
    SharedGlobalConfFactory.setGloablConf(gloablConf);
    Mockito.when(bc.checks(ArgumentMatchers.anyString())).thenReturn(this.decisionParam);
}
@DataProvider(name = "tdpOne")
public static Object[][] testDatasProvider() {
    return new Object[][]{
        {"**AF-argument1**", false, "AF", "DEC1", "Done_another_way DEC1-AF"},
        {"**AT-argument2**", true, "AT", "DEC2", "Done_SO"},
        {"**BF-Argument3**", false, "BF", "DEC3", "Done_another_way DEC3-BF"},
        {"**BT-Argument4**", true, "BT", "DEC4", "Done_SO"}};
}
```

The test is with TestNG and Mockito : it shows how we don't need to do the complex stuff (reading the sql table, the xml files etc..) but simply mock different set of values targeting just our sole business case. *(if a nice fellow would accept to translate in other frameworks for those interested...)*

As for the initial request was about the design allowing to ***reasonably refactor a -huge- existing code-base away from the 'static singleton anti-pattern' , while introducing tests and mocks*** I assume this a quite valid answer.
Will like to hear about your opinion and BETTER alternatives